# Number of nodes in BST in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

```
int numOfNodes(struct node* rootPtr){
    if(rootPtr== NULL) return 0;

    int r = numOfNodes(rootPtr->right);
    int l = numOfNodes(rootPtr->left);
    return r+l+1; 
}
```

Can someone explain to me how this works? Recursion is a bit confusing to me since I'm just starting. I understand that this +1 is for the root node but I don't understand how are r and l increasing.

Comment: It's best if you take out a piece of paper and "run" the program manually with some simple sample data. Start with a 1 node tree, then a root node with just left, then add a right node, etc.

Comment: Imagine you are the root node, and someone asks you how many nodes are in your tree.  You ask both of your children how many nodes are in each of their trees, sum the responses and add 1 (for yourself), and respond.  Each child is doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's run to your code step by step with some example trees, getting more and more complex.

### First example : empty tree

This is kind of an edge case. If the tree is empty, its root node is `NULL` you can see the function will immediately return 0, which is the correct result.

### Second example : tree with one node

In this case our tree is just a single root node, let's call it "A". The structure of the tree looks like this:

```
     (A)
  /       \
NULL     NULL
```

We use `NULL` pointers as leaves to mark that the root node has no children. Let's proceed to the function call.

- You  call `numOfNodes` with `A` as its argument.
- First we check that the argument is not `NULL`, this isn't the case so we continue.
- Then we call `numOfNodes` with `A->right` as argument.

  - We enter **another** `numOfNodes` function, this time with `rootNode = A->right`
  - It turns out that `A->right` is `NULL`. So this call to `numOfNodes` doesn't go past the first `if` and returns 0.
- We return to the initial call to `numOfNodes`, where `r` now has the value 0.
- Then we call `numOfNodes` a third time, this time with `rootNode = A->left` as argument.

  - Similarly, this call to `numOfNodes` immediately returns 0 because `A->left` is `NULL`.
- We return to the initial call to `numOfNodes` where `l` now has the value 0
- We now can return the final result : the number of nodes on the left (0), the number of nodes on the right(0) plus the one we're currently at (1). Total `r+l+1 = 1`, which is the correct result>

You may have noted that during the execution ***the function called another version of itself*** but with a different argument from the one it was initially called with. This idea is a very powerful programming technique called **recursion**, and is especially useful when dealing with trees.

In essence, you start with the root of the tree and ask it to count the number of node on its right, and the number of nodes on its left, then add one. To know the number of nodes on its right, is very simple. You use the same function **as if the node on the right was the root of a new tree**. This may lead to more and more calls to the same counting function, each time with a deeper node as the "fake root". The cascading calls stops when they reaches `NULL` node. Eventually the results "float back" up the tree as each function returns to the one that called it.

## Third example : a more complete tree

Let's suppose we now have a binary tree with more nodes. Say we have this tree of height 3:

```
        __(A)__
     /          \ 
    (B)         (C)
   /   \       /   \
 NULL  (D)   NULL  NULL
      /   \             
    NULL  NULL
```

- We begin by calling `numOfNodes` on the root of the tree, i.e `A`. `A` is not `NULL` so we carry on.
- We call `numOfNodes` with `A->right` as argument.
- We thus enter *another version* (#2) of `numOfNodes` with `A->right` as argument. It turns out that `A->right` is `C` which is not `NULL`. This version of `numOfNodes` does not return 0 immediately.
- We will enter a *third version* of `numOfNodes`, this time with `C->right` as argument.
- It turns out that `C->right` is `NULL` so this version (#3) of `numOfNodes` returns 0
- So the `r` variable in the second version of `numOfNodes` now has the value 0
- The same thing happens when we compute the `l` variable because `C->left` is also `NULL`.
- The second version of `numOfNodes`, the one called with `C`, reaches its final instruction and returns `r+l+1` which is equal to `0+0+1=1` (0 nodes on the left, 0 nodes on the right, plus the "fake root" C).
- We then return to the *first* `numOfNodes`, as we now know that `r` is 1.
- We are now going to compute `l` for this version. For this we will call `numOfNodes` again, this times with `A->left` (i.e. `B`) as argument.
- I won't detail it (I encourage you to do it on paper),  this time we will call `numOfNodes` four more times), and `l` is computed to be equal to `2`.
- The total result is thus 4 (there's 1 node on the right, 2 on the left, plus the root node).

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at this simple tree:

```
  Root
 / \
A   B
   / \
  C   D
```

Then the calls and returns are as follows:

```
numOfNodes( Root )  
    numOfNodes(B)
        numOfNodes(D)
        return 1
        numOfNodes(C)
        return 1
    return 3    
    numOfNodes(A)
    return 1
return 5
```